# How can I show Shopify variants depending on option value

Tags: shopify, liquid, variant

How could you display only certain variants on the product and collection pages in Shopify depending on the value of an option?

Assuming the option name is 'Box Options' and the values would either be 'Trade' or 'Retail' I would expect something similar to this code to return the price for the Trade variant:

```
{%- assign get_variant = product.options_with_values -%}
{% assign trade_variant = get_variant | where: "Trade" %}
<p>{{ trade_variant.price }}</p>
```

For context I'm trying to get trade prices to be used where the customer tag is "Trade" using this if statement in the liquid file:

```
{% if customer.tags contains 'Trade' %}
```

Feel like this should be really easy but for the life of me I cannot get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

If your variants contain only one option, then something like that should work (not tested):

```
{% if customer.tags contains 'Trade' %}
  {% assign p_variants = product.variants | where:'title','Trade' %}
  {% for variant in p_variants %}
    {{ variant.title }}
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Then, second case, your variants go with multiple options, then it is a little bit more complex (not tested either):

```
{% if customer.tags contains 'Trade' %}
  {% for variant in product.variants %}
    {% if variant.options contains 'Box Options' and variant.title contains 'Trade' %}
      {{ variant.title }}
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Many thanks, your first bit of code works, however the second does not.

That said, they were both extremely useful and I am now much more enlightened as to how the variant object works and very close to solving my issue. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad to hear that. Maybe on the second part, only "{% if variant.title contains 'Trade' %} would be necessary.