# Shopify Liquid how to change the source of an image regarding to a specific variant

Tags: javascript, image, shopify, product, liquid

I have created custom product cards, that I am displaying for example on the collection page in shopify. In the product cards I have created a "toggle like" select form where the user can switch the displayed variant. So when the user changes with the select form the variant I want to retrieve the source of the image of the selected variant so I can display it.

```js
const collectionProductTogglePairs = document.querySelectorAll('.Pair');
collectionProductTogglePairs.forEach(collectionProductTogglePair => {
  collectionProductTogglePair.addEventListener('click', function () {
    collectionProductTogglePair.nextElementSibling.style.right = "0";
    collectionProductTogglePair.nextElementSibling.style.left = "auto";
  });
});
const collectionProductToggleSingles = document.querySelectorAll('.Single');
collectionProductToggleSingles.forEach(collectionProductToggleSingle => {
  collectionProductToggleSingle.addEventListener('click', function () {
    collectionProductToggleSingle.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.style.right = "auto";
    collectionProductToggleSingle.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.style.left = "0";
  });
});
```

```css
.custom-card-product-product-image {
 background-image: url({{ card_product.featured_media | product_img_url: '700x'}}); 
}
.custom-card-product-folder-2:before {
 background-image: url({{ card_product.featured_media | product_img_url: '700x'}});
}
```

```html
<div class="custom-card-product-folder">
    <div class="custom-card-product-folder-2"></div>
    <a href="{{ card_product.url }}" class="custom-card-product-product-image"></a>
    <h6 class="custom-card-product-product-title" >{{ card_product.title | escape }}</h6>
    <div class="custom-card-product-product-price {% unless card_product.compare_at_price == blank %}red{% else %}black{% endunless %}"><span class="grey line-through {% unless card_product.compare_at_price == blank %}margin-right-ten{% endunless %}">{{ card_product.compare_at_price | money}}</span> {{ card_product.price | money}}</div>
    <div class="custom-card-product-toggle-wrapper">
    {% for option in card_product.options_with_values %}
    {% if option.name == "Anzahl" %}
    {% for value in option.values %}
      <div class="custom-card-product-toggle-value {{ value }}" test="{{ value.image.src }}">{{ value | escape }}</div>
    {% endfor %}
      <div class="custom-card-product-toggle-active-value-overlay"></div>
    {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to access the product variant based on the option(s) selected, then you can access the [variant.featured_image](https://shopify.dev/api/liquid/objects#variant-featured_image) property, which you can pipe to the [image_url](https://shopify.dev/api/liquid/filters#image_url) filter to get the image url at the appropriate size.

Further info on getting the product variant based on the option can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66316044/how-can-i-show-shopify-variants-depending-on-option-value)